# Is it possible to use hosting startup assemblies with minimal APIs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I am using this package: `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes.HostingStartup`. This is using the hosting startup functionality functionality for ASP.NET Core to register application insights. It works fine if the project is a web api with controllers but I get and exception when trying to use minimal APIs:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Configure>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverCo
ntext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverC
ontext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverC
ontext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.BuildK8sServiceCollection(IServiceCollection services, Func`1 detectKubernetes, IK
ubernetesServiceCollectionBuilder kubernetesServiceCollectionBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.ConfigureKubernetesTelemetryInitializer(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Func
`1 detectKubernetes, IKubernetesServiceCollectionBuilder kubernetesServiceCollectionBuilder, Action`1 applyOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 app
lyOptions, IKubernetesServiceCollectionBuilder kubernetesServiceCollectionBuilder, Func`1 detectKubernetes)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 app
lyOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher(IServiceCollection services)
   at ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes.HostingStartup.K8sInjection.<>c.<Configure>b__0_0(WebHostBuilderContext cxt, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<.ctor>b__6_2(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.BootstrapHostBuilder.RunDefaultCallbacks(ConfigurationManager configuration, HostBuilder innerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder..ctor(WebApplicationOptions options, Action`1 configureDefaults)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(String[] args)
```

Is it possible to use minimal APIs and hosting startup ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that was a problem in the package itself. I updated the package to version `2.0.2-beta2`. It seems to work fine now.